# deduplicates values in array with javascript before GET query

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, duplicates

I have the following loop that list domains. Each line contains a checkbox with domain as value stored in array urls[] :

```
<form action="/profiles-routing/add/63" method="get">
...
        <?php foreach ($accesslogs as $accesslog): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="urls[]" value="<?= $accesslog->DOMAIN ?>">
            </td>
            <td><a href="<?= $accesslog->url ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?= $accesslog->url ?>"><?= $accesslog->DOMAIN ?></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
...
</form>
```

I could have many same domains in the query, I looking how to deduplicate urls values with a javascript before doing the GET query.

For example, javascript should modify this :

http://127.0.0.1:8001/profiles-routing/add/63?urls[0]=www.domaine1.com&urls[1]=www.domaine1.com&urls[2]=www.domaine1.com&urls[3]=www.domaine2.com&urls[4]=www.domaine2.com

To this :
http://127.0.0.1:8001/profiles-routing/add/63?urls[0]=www.domaine1.com&urls[3]=www.domaine2.com

How can I do it ?

Thank you,

Comment: You're getting those domains in PHP, why not sort the duplicates out there instead of JavaScript?

Comment: Why aren't you removing the duplicates in the php?

Comment: You should probably be using php to pre process the $accesslog and de dupe server side

Comment: I need to deduplicate before because I want to reduce the chances to get an error like "Request-URI Too Long". The query can contains hundreds of URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code to help you out:

```
<?php
    function arr_clearduplicates($arr) {
        $newArray = array();

        foreach($arr as $val) {
            //If the value isn't in the array, push it in.
            // This will make sure no existing data is added again.
            if(!in_array($val, $newArray)) {
                $newArray[] = $val;
            }
        }

        return $newArray;
    }
?>
```

This will basically register a function doing this:

1. Take whatever array you give it
2. Make a new empty array.
3. Take all values in your first array, if they are already in the new array, they will not be added, otherwise, they will.
4. Return the empty array.

Which means: array will have no values equal to each other.

Comment: That code is in PHP, I just noticed he did it in Javascript for whatever reason, rip.

Comment: Isn't that just what [array_unique()](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) does?

Comment: I had no clue array_unique() was a thing. I know basic PHP, not the library.

Comment: Your code looks to be run after GET query inside /profiles-routing/add/63 page in my case. I need to deduplicate before because I want to reduce the chances to get an error like "Request-URI Too Long".